# Split up Variable depending on result - SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a variable A2 that can be 4 variables and Null. They are not mutually exclusive. My variable A1 is a department name.

A1: Dispatch, Operations, HR, etc.
A2: Manager, TL, Agents, 4 and NULL.

What I get now just with a simple code (more variables in real code):

```
SELECT
A1,
A2;
```

And the result is:

```
A1           A2
Dispatch     Manager
Dispatch     TL
Dispatch     Agent
Dispatch     NULL
Operations   NULL
HR           Manager
HR           Agent
HR           NULL
```

So, I get the Department as duplicates.

What I want is to remove the duplicated in one out of two ways:

```
A1           Manager           TL           Agent           NULL
Dispatch     Manager           TL           Agent
Operations                                                  NULL
HR           Manager                        Agent
```

OR:

```
A1           A2
Dispatch     Manager, TL, Agent
Operations   NULL
HR           Manager, Agent
```

Anyone have an idea how to get this?

Thanks,

Comment: Distinct is a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, not a function (on a column.) To make things clearer, remove those redundant parentheses, i.e. do `SELECT
DISTINCT A1, A2 ...`.

Comment: This will not change it, I still want to have all the information and just removing the paranthesis will in this case give me the exact same result.

Comment: Didn't say it would. Just make code clearer to understand, for you and for everyone else reading it.

Comment: Use group by followed by aggregate functions on columns select a1,max(a2) from table group by a1;

Comment: For the first way, maybe google for 'SQL Turn rows to columns'

Comment: Aggregation over a CASE for each possible value in A2: `MAX(CASE WHEN A2 = 'Manager' THEN A2 ELSE '' END`

Comment: Folowing my previous comment, [link](https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teradata has [XMLAGG](https://info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/Teradata_Data_Types/B035-1140-160K/ssm1472241245699.html%20%22XMLAGG) for this:

```
select
A1,
trim(trailing ',' from (xmlagg(a2|| ',') (varchar(5000))))
from 
yourtable
group by A1
```